# Windows 7 running slowly with low CPU usage and memory

Tags: windows-7, performance, freeze

I have a relatively new (under 2 yrs old) Windows 7 machine. It has 9GB of RAM, and an i7 core CPU (930 @ 2.8GHz w/ 8 CPUs). After about 8 months since a clean install, I noticed my computer was running slowly. I figure it was fragmentation etc, and I did a complete wipe & clean reinstall.

However, my problems are somehow persisting. The computer is running painfully slowly (but in leaps and bounds - sometimes it will work fine for 3 hrs, then suddenly freeze up just from clicking the start button). The 'freezes' happen randomly - not during any especially intensive computing. I initially thought something might be eating through my CPU and/or Memory, but Task Manager indicates that neither the CPU or Memory spike. In fact, even during serious lag, CPU usage remains at less than 5% and Memory at ~ 1.5GB.

It's beyond me why a fresh install on a powerful machine is performing so poorly. And it certainly is frustrating!  What could be causing the poor performance, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: random freezes point to hardware failure, most likely ram. i also think your "it runs slow because of defragmentation" was a wrong conclusion, defragmentation is not really a problem under win7. check your hw.

Comment: is this happening after you reinstall your OS?

Comment: Does this serious lag also happen when in safe mode?

Comment: You can also use a tool like [HDTune](http://www.hdtune.com/download.html) to examine the performance over the full length of the disk. You are looking for large dips, or a very erratic line which would indicate you either have a poor quality or dying HDD. The kinds of numbers to expect for a single 7400RPM drive would be ~80-130MB/s read and ~10-15ms access time, if you've got RAID or an SSD then its a whole other kettle of fish (and a different set of trouble shooting).

Comment: Be sure to run the tests DURING slow moments - they won't help if they seem to run normally since you would not know which device is not performing optimally.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems like it could be the hard drive dying, which would slow windows down.

Comment: How do I confirm this diagnosis? If this is in fact the case, a assume I will need to purchase & install a new HD?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll get back to you once the check is completed...

Comment: Also worth monitoring the HDD light and/or the resource monitor (open task manager, go over to performance, click on resource monitor, go over to disk tab).  Also, the standard troubleshooting advice:  find all of the most updated drivers you can and use those (incl motherboard, gpu, any peripherals, etc)
Also, quibbling over semantics, you have four hyperthreaded CPUs.  There is a difference.

Comment: After switching hard drives for my boot drive, it turned out that my boot drive was VERY slow. Because this is where I had my important stuff (programs and whatnot) it had some pretty nasty effects. I just shuffled my HDs and everything was better.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I'm pretty sure it's not hardware related seeing as there's absolutely no problem in Linux.

Answer (score 25):

These symptoms sound like a CPU throttling issue that I had. When my laptop overheated, the CPU would reduce its speed (throttle back) to reduce heat output... as a result my CPU % appeared to be low at around 15%, but in fact the CPU had cycled back to 16% of its max and so it was in fact running flat out.

You can diagnose this by using Resource Monitor instead of Task Manager. (Type "resmon" into the Start-Run prompt.) At the top of the CPU tab processes window there is a useful "Maximum frequency" which will reduce as the CPU throttles back.

If this is the problem then you can look at causes of the throttling. You can use free tools like Speedfan to monitor temperature and check on your fans.

In my case there was a definite correlation between throttling and temperature. My laptop was a Dell E6400 and I used a fan assisted cooling tray to assist with the overheating, and I also hit a known issue with this laptop model - see http://www.xtremesystems.org/forums/showthread.php?240717-Dell-Latitude-E6500-E6400-ThrottleGate-Fix

Comment: Thanks for this info. This led me to check out my power plan, which was set to a plan that reduces my computer's performance. Switching to the High performance plan, gave me full CPU power again. I was considering buying a new laptop because of this issue, so this saved me lots of cash! Thanks!

Comment: Cool.  I can't believe I hadn't heard of `resmon` before!

Comment: I had same "Maximum Frequency" problem, it stuck on 29%, and my Power plan was on "High performance". Turned out cpu's fan was dead and laptop turned CPU throttling on to safe cpu from overhitting

Comment: Checking the "Maximum frequency" in the Resource Monitor is a good advice. I my case it was stuck at 30%. I could not fix it by restarting Windows (10), but by switching off and on the PC. After that it would go up beyond 100%.

Answer (score 3):

This might be caused by the selected Power Plan. The "Balanced" power plan recommended by Windows is not very clever and can affect the performance badly (50% in my case).

So: check the Maximum Frequency in the Resource Monitor, like [SteveW explained](https://superuser.com/questions/427276/windows-7-running-slowly-with-low-cpu-usage-and-memory/468498#468498). If the Maximum Frequency is not 100% check the Power Plan (battery icon in your tray bar).

Set the Power Plan to High Performance. If it solves the problem then you can start playing around with other plans or configurations but at least you have identified the issue.

Comment: An answer from three years ago has already been accepted.

Comment: ...but, @suspectus, Stack Exchange Q&As are also (or: *above all*) meant to be archives for future visitors who have the same problem? The more possible solutions the better then, I'd say, and this seems to have been the solution for Fernando.

Answer (score 2):

1) Run Windows Memory Test: Start->Control Panel->type "memory"->Diagnose your computer's memory problems.  That will run the Windows memory diagnostic and it's a good place to start.

2) Run Command Prompt as administrator and then type "chkdsk /r" and hit enter.  Follow instructions.  That will check the integrity of your install.

If you had extra RAM lying around you could easily switch that out and see if it helped.  It's possible that your video card is maybe acting up but that's just me trying to think of all the conceivable issues.

Answer (score 0):

IF you generate these two log files and post it somewhere for me, I can tell you exactly why it runs slow. Some will be high probability, background indexing or security scans, others may be rogues.
http://www.geekstogo.com/2010/05/27/otl-by-oldtimer-a-modern-replacement-for-hijackthis/ 
I've done this hundreds of times so I can read these logs.. Not for the newbie to analyze, but anyone can run it. ITs called OTL.exe

**added**

My usual findings are excessive slugware or good programs when used in combinations of certain others, make a quad core tower into a dinosaur at times.  One of the biggest slugs can be in some cases, using >1MB host files which are readin periodically into separate memory caches by EVERY active app. that uses web for updates or has firewall privvies. This in combination with the File INdex service plus a massive AV solution with a 4 or more services. I have solutions to all of these and hundreds of more reasons why OTL.exe can tell me exactly what is slowing down your PC. BTW. The Task mgr only records a snapshot of CPU useage every 15ms and apps which run short threads and exit or use hidden features or consume a lot of hidden time in maintenance are not recorded in Task Mgr. Hence 2%cpu usage means nothing. There are better tools , procmon.exe , Mark Russinovich® free tool, being one, to see what is happening. I digress but can prove what I promise.

**I will reply with a list of suggestions and recommendations for you to fix your own PC and learn why / what/ how to make and keep it screaming fast and stay secure.**

Disk errors can easily be found in the System log file. BLoated or corrupt MFT's or backup $mft files can be bloated or corrupt can contribute to delays and remedied with run> chkdsk /f (y on reboot). But none of these are sufficient to explain your symptoms on their own.

Msconfig.exe is a primitive tool that just scratches the surface and does not show hidden files, processes, services or rogue drivers, rootkit, or bootkits.

THe choice is yours.  Trial and error or get help from a Windows expert.(moi)

**Update 5/25**
Having reviewed your OTL.exe *log files*, the results have raised a few questions in my mind, but still no certainty to actual random system stalls at your end. I can indicate few high probability areas of high risk. Further feedback from you on when this starte and how often it occurs will help me.

Generally, you have evidence of reasonable security and evidence of common insecurities.

Security minded Apps

- Microsoft Security Client
- Windows Defender
- Avast
- SpyBot
- PeerBlock

Unknown traffic load

- LogMeIn
- FileZilla FTP
- PowerIso
- Dropbox
- uTorrent

There are a few other startups that may be sluggish but.... since this was a clean install of Win7x64 on May 13th, when did it behave acceptable last ?

Comment: Ok, the log is available here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Xmt9ZkTV. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Before May 13th. I just ran combofix.exe, no go there, I'm still having issues.

Answer (score 0):

This is in response to OTL.exe log in support of previous answer. (need more than 600 char) So it is an extended answer.

1. Routine - **update spybot at your leisure**
   http://www.safer-networking.org/en/mirrors/index.html for your lang.

   - spybot - search & destroy\DelZip179.dll" on line 8.  The value "*" of 
     attribute "language" in element "assemblyIdentity" is invalid.
   - **send above to detections(at)spybot.info** ( Spybot tech ) if update repeats error. They will resolve. (common issue)
2. Urgent - Real-Time Protection feature has encountered an error and failed.

> Microsoft Antimalware | ID = 2001 , ... has encountered an error
>   trying to update signatures,  Current Engine Version: 1.1.8304.0
>   Previous: 1.1.8403.0 , Another version of this product is already
>   installed. Installation of this version cannot continue. **To
>   configure or remove the existing version of this product, use
>   Add/Remove Programs on the Control Panel**.

**If that fails (See Event Viewer) call MS (free security support 800-xxx) and resolve.**

These are just results not the cause of your issue. OTL.exe generates two log files. I need the other to figure the cause. Most likely infect App installed and need combofix.exe from Bleepingcomputer.com to clean. Will advise later, when you send 2nd log from OTL.exe. Best advice is stay in safe mode or dont run.

Comment: Apologies - here's the Extra.txt file. http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=frUsxkXY

Comment: no problem but try again.. same file

Comment: Still waiting for the other file Not the same one.

Comment: If you are not going to provide the requested info, Someone may as well close the question as I suspect my comments were valid ( corrupt App. infected system.. clean with combofix.exe may be most expedient solution.)

Comment: Gah, apologies - here is the other file: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=sGM9kK78

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and if I tell you the problem: You will laugh.

I have (accidentally) place an a very old CD in the CD drive and forgot it.
Then when I have got the issue, I was checking every thing: from memory diagnosis to chkdsk.
I have just heard some sound the CD drive and removed it.